# python 2d list initialization error by using arr = [0 * size] * size

Tags: python, list

I was trying to initialize a 2D list in python by `arr = [0 * size] * size`.
When I assigned value 1 to the position arr[0][0], arr[1][1],arr[2][2]....., somehow all the positions were assigned to 1. I am confused which part I did wrong. Thank you

```
n = 3
dp = [[0] * n] * n
print (dp)
for i in range(n):
    dp[i][i] = 1
print(dp)
```

```
#result from pycharm
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 0):

The wrong part is the initialization of the 2D array. Use  `dp = [ [0] * n for _ in range(n) ]` instead.

Your code does not work because the last `*` does a shallow copy. It copies the address of the object (list), so all `n` lists are in fact the same one.